# Convert Jquery toggle to mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools

I need to convert the jquery script into a mootools 1.2.5 script.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
      $('ul li').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
      return false;
    }).children("ul").hide();
});
```

The Shopping Cart Software I use works only with mootools.
JQuery influenced negatively mootools.

`noConflict` is not working.

I found this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rCfwq/).

But this I can't use either because `display:none;` & `display:block;` for the UL and LI is anchored in almost every line of the whole css and that is to insane to change the whole css.

Answer (score 0):

I understand correctly that you want to toggle the visibility of each level?
Try this javascript ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rCfwq/84/)):

```
$$('#main li').each(function(obj, index) {
    obj.addEvent('click', function(e) {
      this.getFirst('ul').toggleClass('show');
      this.addClass('show');
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```